# SLOC in a git commit

Tags: regex, git

I have a file that has a list of commit ids in it and I'm trying to write a script that calculates the number of lines in each commit. What is the easiest/best way to do this? I already have a few lines of python written, but I'm open to any language really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--numstat` (for per-file changes) or `--shortstat` (for the sum of the changes) as an argument to `git show`, `git log`, or `git diff-tree`.

For example, in bash:

```
while read sha; do
  git diff-tree --shortstat $sha $sha^
done
```

Note that the various diffstat flags can be passed to almost any git command that examines a commit, but they are only documented in the man page of [git-diff-tree](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff-tree.html).

Comment: Won't that tell me the lines between commits? I need the number of lines a commit added. Like if you were to download the commit as a patch, how many lines does that patch add?

Comment: That’s what diffstat means. Number of insertions and number of deletions.

Comment: Thanks, works great when I only provide one sha. This will still require some post-processing, but I was expecting that.